# select duplicate values from the oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle table which does not have any pk set up for some other reasons. It has 5 columns and I would like to be able to remove the duplicate records (if 5 column values are the same, they are duplicate). I have come up with this SQL, but it looks like this is not picking up the duplicate values:

```
SELECT DATE_TIME, SITE, RESPONSE_TIME, AVAIL_PERCENT, AGENT
FROM table_name
GROUP BY DATE_TIME, SITE, RESPONSE_TIME, AVAIL_PERCENT, AGENT

HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

SAMPLE RECORDS:

```
DATE_TIME                   SITE                                                                        RESPONSE_TIME AVAIL_PERCENT AGENT
20-Apr-13 04.23.00.00 AM    Live Site (TxP)[IE]-Logon To My Accounts - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]    8.2610  100.00  45693
20-Apr-13 10.23.00.00 AM    Live Site (TxP)[IE]-Logon To My Accounts - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]    6.2900  100.00  45693
24-Apr-13 07.22.00.00 AM    Live Site (TxP)[IE]-Online Home Page - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]    3.7300  100.00  45693
24-Apr-13 03.52.00.00 AM    Live Site (TxP)[IE]-Online Home Page - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]    3.7180  100.00  45693
08-May-13 06.52.00.00 AM    Live Site (TxP)[IE]-Online Home Page - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]    3.5970  100.00  45693
20-May-13 01.52.00.00 AM    Live Site (TxP)[IE]-Online Home Page - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]    3.7910  100.00  45693
25-Apr-13 01.52.00.00 AM    Live Site (TxP)[IE]-Online Home Page - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]    3.3400  100.00  45693
08-May-13 05.22.00.00 AM    Live Site (TxP)[IE]-Online Home Page - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]    2.4410  100.00  45693
09-May-13 01.22.00.00 AM    Live Site (TxP)[IE]-Online Home Page - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]            45693
21-May-13 06.52.00.00 AM    Live Site (TxP)[IE]-Online Home Page - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]    3.5480  100.00  45693
23-Apr-13 02.23.00.00 AM    Live Site (TxP)[IE]-Logon To My Accounts - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]    10.7070 100.00  45693
26-Apr-13 09.22.00.00 AM    Live Site (TxP)[IE]-Online Home Page - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]    4.0070  100.00  45693
26-Apr-13 03.52.00.00 AM    Live Site (TxP)[IE]-Online Home Page - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]    3.9350  100.00  45693
22-May-13 12.52.00.00 PM    Live Site (TxP)[IE]-Online Home Page - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]    4.1760  100.00  45693
23-Apr-13 02.53.00.00 AM    Live Site (TxP)[IE]-Logon To My Accounts - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]    6.9500  100.00  45693
23-Apr-13 03.23.00.00 AM    Live Site (TxP)[IE]-Logon To My Accounts - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]    6.0480  100.00  45693
23-Apr-13 04.23.00.00 AM    Live Site (TxP)[IE]-Logon To My Accounts - User Time (seconds)[Geo Mean]    6.7600  100.00  45693
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: Your sql looks right...  Are you sure the times and all the fields are exact duplicates?

Comment: @sgeddes, when I run that sql above, I get that sampe output. They are not duplicates, all of the values are different.

Comment: @user1471980 You're grouping by all the fields, what you see is the result of the grouping, not the individual records behind the groups

Comment: they are all different because you're seeing a result set that is unique on the columns in the group by clause. Include the count(*) and you'll see how many rows there are with those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the rowid as a pseudo-primary key, and run a query that deletes rows such as:

```
delete from
  my_table
where
  rowid not in (
    select   min(rowid)
    from     my_table
    group by column_1,
             column_2,
             column_3,
             etc)
```

The column_1 etc are the set of columns that define uniqueness for the row.

There may be better performing options for very large data sets with a high number of duplicates, but this is a quick method that is often sufficient.

Comment: that did not work. Before deleteing, I did a select, and seeing that the recorcds that come back are not duplicates.

Comment: Do you mean that you ran the subquery and found that it returned rowids for records that have no duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

As you are on Oracle, you can try the following to remove the duplicates:

```
DELETE my_table WHERE ROWID IN
(
  SELECT ROWID FROM
  (
    SELECT 
    DATE_TIME, SITE, RESPONSE_TIME, AVAIL_PERCENT, AGENT, ROWID, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
      DATE_TIME, SITE, RESPONSE_TIME, AVAIL_PERCENT, AGENT ORDER BY DATE_TIME) ITM_IDX
    FROM my_table
  )
  WHERE ITM_IDX > 1
);
```

Comment: yes, this is an oracle table. I ran your select statment, I get this eror: "missing window specification for this function"

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to create a primary key?
You can create a table for your exceptions and Oracle will put the records who violated the primary key for you in that table.
The primary key itself will not be created if there's a violaion, but you can analyze the bad data afterwards. =)

```
create table tb1 
(field1 number, field2 varchar2(100));

--good data
insert into tb1 values (1, 'a');
insert into tb1 values (1, 'b');
insert into tb1 values (1, 'c');
insert into tb1 values (2, 'a');
insert into tb1 values (2, 'b');
insert into tb1 values (2, 'c');
-- bad data
insert into tb1 values (3, 'a');
insert into tb1 values (3, 'a');
commit;

-- a table for exceptions
create table tbl_exceptions (row_id rowid,
                             owner varchar2(30),
                             table_name varchar2(30),
                             constraint varchar2(30));

-- the primary key
-- if it fails, you have repeated registers
alter table tb1 add constraint pk1 primary key (field1, field2)
exceptions into tbl_exceptions;

-- bad data will be here
-- please notice its 'ROW_ID' from the second table
select tb1.*
from  tb1,
      tbl_exceptions 
where tb1.rowid = tbl_exceptions.row_id;
```